# Switch statement produces incorrect result

Tags: winforms, function, powershell, return

I'm creating a script for our support department and interns. I have a working script but wanted to use a GUI to it a bit easier for our interns. At this moment I'm pulling my hair out right now, I've copied the function below and and would like to have the value of `$task1_exec`. But when I try to put the return `$Result` in a variable the `$Task1` variable is printed not the `$Task1_exec` one.

```
$FormTitle = "Formtitle" 
$ScriptPath = $(get-location).Path;

$task1 = "Task 1"
$task1_exec = "Perform task 1"
$task2 = "Task 2"
$task2_exec = "Perform task 2"
$task3 = "Task 3"
$task3_exec = "Perform task 3"
$task4 = "Task 4"
$task4_exec = "Perform task 4"

function Prompt-SelectionList
{
    Param(
        [Parameter(Position=0,Mandatory=$true)][string]$Description,
        [Parameter(Position=1,Mandatory=$true)][string[]]$List
    )

    [void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
    [void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing") 

    $Form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
    $Form.Text = $FormTitle
    $Form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(500,450) #(300,200) 
    $Form.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"    

    $btnOK = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
    $btnOK.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(125,375)
    $btnOK.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(125,25)
    $btnOK.Text = "Run..."
    $Form.Controls.Add($btnOK)

    $btnCancel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
    $btnCancel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(250,375)
    $btnCancel.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(125,25)
    $btnCancel.Text = "Exit"
    $btnCancel.Add_Click({ $script:Result = $null; $Form.Close() })
    $Form.Controls.Add($btnCancel)

    $Label = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
    $Label.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,20)
    $Label.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(480,20)
    $Label.Text = $Description
    $Form.Controls.Add($Label)

    $ListBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListBox
    $ListBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,40)
    $ListBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(460,330)
    $List | ForEach-Object { [void] $ListBox.Items.Add($_) }
    $Form.Controls.Add($ListBox)

    $Form.KeyPreview = $True
    $Form.Add_KeyDown({ if ($_.KeyCode -eq "Enter") { $script:Result = $ListBox.SelectedItem; $Form.Close() }})
    $Form.Add_KeyDown({ if ($_.KeyCode -eq "Escape") { $script:Result = $null; $Form.Close() }})
    $btnOK.Add_Click({ $script:Result = $ListBox.SelectedItem; $Form.Close() })

    $Form.Topmost = $True
    $Form.Add_Shown({ $Form.Activate() })

    [void] $Form.ShowDialog()

    return $Result
}

function Do-PromptTask
{   
    switch -wildcard (Prompt-SelectionList "Chose task to run:" @($task1,$task2,$task3,$task4))
    {
        $task1{$task1_exec}
        $task2{$task2_exec}
        $Task3{$task3_exec}
        $Task4{$task4_exec}
        ""{Exit} #End Selection (cancel selected)
        # "*"{Do-PromptTask} #Keep prompting until "cancel" selected
    }
}

Do-PromptTask
```

My wish is that I could return `$task1_exec` to a variable so when `Do-PromptTask` is finished the return can be used to call another script

```
. ".\Bin\$Result.ps1"
```

Comment: You return the task label from the `Promp-SelectionList` function so that your `switch` can match on it. Isn't that what you want to be doing? If you want `Do-PromptTask` to return the value of `$taskX_exec` shouldn't you just return that value from the appropriate block in the `switch`?

Comment: `return $script:Result`, the function has a scope of its own

Comment: Can't reproduce your problem. The code works just fine when I run it from a PowerShell console or script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're on the right track.

Let's pretend I run Do-PromptTask, chose Task 1, and click Run...

The $result variable from Prompt-SelectionList is passed back to the Switch statement and is **out of scope at this point**. The switch is doing its job and matching the conditional which then prints $task1_exec, but $result is of no use at this point. If you want to store $task1_exec as a variable, you'd need to set something equal to it. However, I will say you could just act on it in the switch statement *without* storing it in a variable, if that makes sense.

Less code approach...

```
    function Do-PromptTask
{   
    switch -wildcard (Prompt-SelectionList "Chose task to run:" @($task1,$task2,$task3,$task4))
    {
        $task1{Invoke-Expression $task1_exec}
        $task2{Invoke-Expression  $task2_exec}
        $Task3{Invoke-Expression  $task3_exec}
        $Task4{Invoke-Expression  $task4_exec}
        ""{Exit} #End Selection (cancel selected)
        # "*"{Do-PromptTask} #Keep prompting until "cancel" selected
    }
}
```

If you're set on storing the variable, you could do something like this...

```
    function Do-PromptTask
{   
    switch -wildcard (Prompt-SelectionList "Chose task to run:" @($task1,$task2,$task3,$task4))
    {
        $task1{$task_result = $task1_exec}
        $task2{$task_result = $task2_exec}
        $Task3{$task_result = $task3_exec}
        $Task4{$task_result = $task4_exec}
        ""{Exit} #End Selection (cancel selected)
        # "*"{Do-PromptTask} #Keep prompting until "cancel" selected
    }
    Invoke-Expression $task_result
}
```

Comment: This awnser is perfect, I've changed the Invoke-Expression to:  `Invoke-Expression "$ScriptPath\Bin\$task_result.ps1"` And set `$task1_exec = "test"` So the output and executed file is: c:\folder\bin\test.ps1 Thanks for your help!